# How can I run onPress function when Slidable is closing

Tags: flutter, slider

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBF2q.png)

After sliding the product, I made it turn off automatically. I want to do some operations while it is automatically shutting down, how can I do this? I want to perform the operations I perform in onPressed while it is automatically closing.

```
 Slidable(
                        closeOnScroll: true,
                        key: UniqueKey(),
                        endActionPane: ActionPane(
                          extentRatio: 0.1,
                          openThreshold: 0.2,
                          closeThreshold: 0.1,
                          motion: const BehindMotion(),
                         
                          children: [
                            SlidableAction(
                              key: UniqueKey(),
                              onPressed: (context) {
                                item.selectedCount = 0;
                                item.isSelected = false;
                                widget.providerValue.selectedCheckItem
                                    ?.remove(item);

                                widget.providerValue.notifyListeners();
                              },
                              backgroundColor: context.suit200Red,
                              icon: Icons.delete,
                              label: 'İptal',
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        child: MaxListTile()
```

Comment: Which part of the code you made it turn off **automatically**?

Comment: Well if you see in the package's code in `flutter_slidable-3.0.0/lib/src/scrolling_behavior.dart`, the automatic closing is handled by the `handleScrollingChanged` method which doesn't seem to have any way to provide a callback

Comment: Yes, I am using version 3.0.0. So how can I find another solution? What I want to do is to change the "isEnabled = true" value of the products I selected in the list to "isEnabled = false" with the slideable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
dismissible: DismissiblePane(onDismissed: () {}),
```

Comment: Yes, I actually tried this, but that's not what I want, what I want to do is uncheck the products I selected.